# What is this superscript problem with omega and Omega?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I get the problem explained below with Overleaf and Texstudio.

The MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\begin{document}


\noindent The coding

\begin{verbatim}
$\Omegaˆ+$ and $\omegaˆ+$ superscripts do not work.

But subscripts work, as here $\Omega_+$ \ and here \ $\omega_+$.
\end{verbatim}

\noindent produces

\medskip

$\Omegaˆ+$ and $\omegaˆ+$ superscripts do not work.

But subscripts work, as here $\Omega_+$ \ and here \ $\omega_+$.
\medskip

\noindent \begin{verbatim}
 Using \(, $$,  or \[ does not fix the problem.
\end{verbatim}

\noindent However, \begin{verbatim}
    \(n_0\cdot 2^{\ell(n_1)}+n_1\)
\end{verbatim}


\smallskip

produces
 \(n_0\cdot 2^{\ell(n_1)}+n_1. \)

 \medskip

\noindent Test with other Greek letters give

\medskip

\noindent $\alpha^+\beta^+\gamma^+\Gamma^+\delta^+\Delta^+\epsilon^+\eta^+\zeta^+\eta^+\theta^+\Theta^+\iota^+\kappa^+\lambda^+\Lambda^+\mu^+\nu^+\xi^+\Xi^+\pi^+\Pi^+\rho^+\sigma^+\Sigma^+\tau^+\upsilon^+\phi^+\Phi^+\chi^+\psi^+\Psi^+ $

\medskip

\noindent The document has 403 other occurrences of the superscript-construction as in $a^b$, from

\begin{verbatim}
    $a^b$,
\end{verbatim}
and there does not appear to be any problems with any of those. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm... you're not using the proper caret there... Note the difference between ˆ and ^.

Comment: @Werner If so, I don't understand why it works for the other Greek letters, and for the more than 400 other occurrences for producing superscript. I use Shift-6 on the Mac Air keyboard, to produce the symbol.

Comment: Because you are using the correct caret with the other Greek letters.

Comment: @cabohah Strange - now it works! Why did I get the wrong character earlier from Shift-6, and now the correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Werner told in a comment, the `ˆ` used at `$\Omegaˆ+$ and $\omegaˆ+$` is not the same as the `^` used at `$\alpha^+\beta^+\gamma^+…`. The first one is wrong, the last one is correct. Therefore:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\begin{document}


\noindent The coding

\begin{verbatim}
$\Omega^+$ and $\omega^+$ superscripts do work.

But subscripts work, as here $\Omega_+$ \ and here \ $\omega_+$.
\end{verbatim}

\noindent produces

\medskip

$\Omega^+$ and $\omega^+$ superscripts do work.

But subscripts work, as here $\Omega_+$ \ and here \ $\omega_+$.
\medskip

\noindent \begin{verbatim}
 Using \(, $$,  or \[ does not fix the problem.
\end{verbatim}

\noindent However, \begin{verbatim}
    \(n_0\cdot 2^{\ell(n_1)}+n_1\)
\end{verbatim}


\smallskip

produces
 \(n_0\cdot 2^{\ell(n_1)}+n_1. \)

 \medskip

\noindent Test with other Greek letters give

\medskip

\noindent $\alpha^+\beta^+\gamma^+\Gamma^+\delta^+\Delta^+\epsilon^+\eta^+\zeta^+\eta^+\theta^+\Theta^+\iota^+\kappa^+\lambda^+\Lambda^+\mu^+\nu^+\xi^+\Xi^+\pi^+\Pi^+\rho^+\sigma^+\Sigma^+\tau^+\upsilon^+\phi^+\Phi^+\chi^+\psi^+\Psi^+ $

\medskip

\noindent The document has 403 other occurrences of the superscript-construction as in $a^b$, from

\begin{verbatim}
    $a^b$,
\end{verbatim}
and there does not appear to be any problems with any of those. 

\end{document}
```

works. So the problem is not `\Omega` but `ˆ` and you should do a global search&replace of the wrong character.

BTW: The `ˆ` is defined as `\textasciicircum` and therefore you should get a warning message:

> `LaTeX Warning: Command \textasciicircum invalid in math mode on input line 22.`

with your example.

Comment: As I wrote in a comment above, it now works. But why did I get the wrong character from Shift-6 earlier, and now the correct one?

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal If you really used the same input but got another character please ask the Mac guys. This is IMHO not a LaTeX question (and even not the one you asked above).

Comment: Indeed, I get the yellow warning Command \textasciicircum invalid in math mode on input line 24.

Comment: Of course, it is not the same question. I was only expressing some frustration.

Comment: It now works in the main document, as the Mac learned to type the caret properly for some inscrutable reason. Many thanks to you, and @Werner!

Answer (score 2):

In `utf8enc.dfu` we find

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02C6}{\textasciicircum}
```

and indeed your log file contains two instances of

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \textasciicircum invalid in math mode on input line 22.
```

Note that U+02C6 MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT isn't the same as U+005E CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT.

Only the latter can be used for superscripts.

Perhaps your keyboard has strange settings (or you're copy-pasting from a PDF and the OS is doing wrong guesses).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\noindent The coding
\begin{verbatim}
$\Omegaˆ+$ and $\omegaˆ+$ superscripts do not work.
\end{verbatim}
produces
$\Omegaˆ+$ and $\omegaˆ+$ superscripts do not work.

\medskip

\noindent Yes, they do if you use the proper character

\medskip

\noindent The coding
\begin{verbatim}
$\Omega^+$ and $\omega^+$ works.
\end{verbatim}
produces
$\Omega^+$ and $\omega^+$ works.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Doing a “search and replace” is best, but you can also decide to have U+02C6 to stand for a `^`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ˆ}{^}

\begin{document}

$\Omegaˆ+$ and $\omegaˆ+$ works.

$\Omega^+$ and $\omega^+$ works.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't recommend doing it, though.

Comment: Thanks! Unlike some Norwegian government members, I am not in the business of copying from the work of others. :)

I will attempt to understand your contribution better next week.